# Android giving out of memory when loading a small image Drawable

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, out-of-memory

I am wondering how are image drawables are loaded into memory when they are used in a view.

My problem is that I have a big-dimensioned image (about 600x700), which only weights 4kb. I thought there was no need to create a 9-patch image as the image is small enough. However when I try to use this image as background, Android is giving me out-of-memory error.

```
06-28 14:54:09.359: E/dalvikvm-heap(2272): Out of memory on a 6816336-byte allocation.
06-28 14:54:09.359: I/dalvikvm(2272): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
06-28 14:54:09.359: I/dalvikvm(2272):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a5d460 self=0x12828
06-28 14:54:09.359: I/dalvikvm(2272):   | sysTid=2272 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074603144
06-28 14:54:09.359: I/dalvikvm(2272):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=162 stm=18 core=0
06-28 14:54:09.359: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
06-28 14:54:09.359: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
06-28 14:54:09.359: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
06-28 14:54:09.359: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
06-28 14:54:09.359: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
06-28 14:54:09.359: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
06-28 14:54:09.359: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
06-28 14:54:09.359: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
06-28 14:54:09.359: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
06-28 14:54:09.359: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)
06-28 14:54:09.359: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:11588)
06-28 14:54:09.359: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at com.telcel.olmpiadas2012.gui.viewcontrollers.medals.MedalsDetail.<init>(MedalsDetail.java:14)
06-28 14:54:09.359: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at com.telcel.olmpiadas2012.gui.viewcontrollers.medals.MedalsHomeVC.onCreate(MedalsHomeVC.java:53)
06-28 14:54:09.359: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-28 14:54:09.359: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-28 14:54:09.367: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
06-28 14:54:09.367: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
06-28 14:54:09.367: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
06-28 14:54:09.367: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
06-28 14:54:09.367: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-28 14:54:09.367: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-28 14:54:09.367: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
06-28 14:54:09.367: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 14:54:09.367: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-28 14:54:09.367: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-28 14:54:09.367: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-28 14:54:09.367: I/dalvikvm(2272):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have added other big images as backgrounds with no problem, and I doubt that my app is taking all but 4kb of the memory space, because other activities load more resources than this one and I have no trouble accessing them.

Should I take into account other aspects rather than final image byte-size?

Answer (score 0):

A Bitmap is not compressed and the 600x700 size makes it very big for the memory, if the quality is not a problem you can try to scale it down.

Edit:

600*700*32/8= 1680000

Comment: What does your numbers represent? . If I decide to scale it down, how big should my image be then?